# MySQL injection MariaDB server version error

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I am getting a syntax error while trying to build my query for a login system. It worked once but when I restarted my XAMPP server it started showing the error. Don't know what's the deal

```
try{

                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login", "root", "");

                String user = textField1.getText();
                String pass = String.valueOf(passwordField1.getPassword());
                try{
                String sql = "select * from tbl_login where `name` =?, `password` =?";
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setString(1, user);
                st.setString(2,pass);

                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                if(rs.next()){
                    welcom w = new welcom();

                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please check you username and password again");
                    textField1.setText("");
                    passwordField1.setText("");
                }
                }
                catch (Exception h){
                    System.out.println(h.getMessage());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

its showing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, `password` =?' at line 1

Comment: Remove the "`" characters around name and password.

Comment: Concatinate conditions in where clause with and not with comma.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this document to see how to use PreparedStatement interface in correct way
https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

Answer (score 2):

When you use a prepared statement, pass the `sql` string when you create the statement, not when you execute it.

```
String sql = "select * from tbl_login where `name` =? and `password` =?";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, user);
st.setString(2,pass);

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( );
                               ^ do not pass the sql query here
```

When you use `st.executeQuery(sql)`, it executes that query directly, but without parsing it for parameter placeholders. So the `?` placeholders are not recognized.

Also you should use the boolean operator `AND` in your where clause, instead of a comma.

---

Regarding your comments:

Your original query used this syntax:

```
...where `name` =?, `password` =?
```

I assume you mean that both conditions must be true. The way to express this in SQL is like the following:

```
...where `name` =? AND `password` =?
```

This is called a Boolean expression. You should have learned about this in any programming class or book, or even some math classes.

A comma does not mean the same as the `AND` operator. SQL uses comma in some other types of expressions, but not as an operator between conditions in the `where` clause.

Comment: i did changed that result set part and it resolved the error but now a new error popped up. Though didn't understood the part where you said to use the AND operator, it would be helpful if you light up the cause of using this operator. And this is the new error I am facing after the edits...

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' `password` ='hello'' at line 1

Comment: This answer is excellent, but back-ticks ` `` ` are not standard SQL, that would be double quote `"` (for keyword or special characters as name). In java String `\"` and `password` is an SQL function I believe.

Comment: @JoopEggen, the question is tagged for mysql and mariadb. In those databases, back-ticks are the only reliable identifier delimiter. Double-quotes are used as identifier delimiters only if you set the right sql mode, but it is not the default.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes I remember. It is only weird that the error has a problem at `password = 'hello'` (password in ticks). So either standard compatibility is set, or the password column has the password encrypted and you would need to write ` **``password`` = password(?)`** - using the password function.

Comment: @JoopEggen, The error is caused by the OP's use of comma instead of a boolean operator.

Comment: @BillKarwin my excuses. Should not have reacted on "it worked once"

Comment: @BillKarwin are you talking about the setStrings that i did using ",".

Comment: I showed you exactly what you did wrong in my answer above, and how to fix it. Please read it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed that part and yes it worked successfully.